# Starting a java service packaged as rpm in Unix through systemctl

Tags: java, unix, jvm, rpm, systemctl

So, I have a java maven project which packages itself into a rpm which will run as a background service in Unix environment through systemctl and have my init file for it. My doubt is if I start new service will it use same JVM which the old service is using or use a new JVM?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will use the same `/usr/bin/java` (or other location it is set) executable that the old service used,
in order to start a new `java` process instance with it. Therefore: a new JVM.

You will have a new JVM for each service started.

Comment: So, will using a different executable result in using same JVM ?

Comment: @Flanker No. See the creation of a JVM like the creation of an execution environment. If it happened that the same execution environment was used one day, then all the data would be shared between the applications that you would be running. And of course, this is not wished, and this not the case. Each java call creates one process in its own JVM.